# The requested resource is not available Tomcat 7 Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

i installed Maven und want to check out the project from this page:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/spring-data-mongodb-and-jsf-integration-tutorial.html

I did make these steps:

1. I loaded the src and pom.xml file from Github
2. I copied the files in
       the workspace from eclipse an change the project name with no
       whitespaces.
3. I used the m2eclipse wtp plugin from eclipse to 
       `Import > Maven > Existing Maven Project`
4. I make `Run As > Maven
       install`
5. I get i `build success` message

After i have installed the project i look a the `Project > Properties < Project Facets`. The dynamic web module was not klicked. So i klicked it.
After this i klicked on the webapp Folder Build Path and adding the Folder to the Build path to have the src/main webapp.

I think these steps are correct.
But then i want to start the project as a dynamic web project i get the error
`HTTP Status 404 - The request resource is not available`

The console message:

```
Jan 30, 2014 11:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener ini Information:
The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45;C:\elipse_jee\eclipse;;.
Jan 30, 2014 11:28:14 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
Warnung: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:springDataMongodbExample' did not find a matching property.
Jan 30, 2014 11:28:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Information: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 30, 2014 11:28:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Information: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 30, 2014 11:28:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Information: Initialization processed in 1456 ms
Jan 30, 2014 11:28:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Information: Starting service Catalina
Jan 30, 2014 11:28:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Information: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Jan 30, 2014 11:28:16 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
Information: Mojarra 2.2.0 ( ) für Kontext '' wird initialisiert.
Jan 30, 2014 11:28:16 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
Information: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy-Annotationen vorhanden.  Verwaltete Bean-Methoden, die mit diesen Annotationen markiert sind, lassen die entsprechenden Annotationen verarbeiten.
Jan 30, 2014 11:28:17 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
Information: Mojarra 2.2.0 ( ) für Kontext '/springDataMongodbExample' wird initialisiert.
Jan 30, 2014 11:28:17 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
Information: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy-Annotationen vorhanden.  Verwaltete Bean-Methoden, die mit diesen Annotationen markiert sind, lassen die entsprechenden Annotationen verarbeiten.
Jan 30, 2014 11:28:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Information: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 30, 2014 11:28:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Information: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 30, 2014 11:28:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Information: Server startup in 3100 ms
```

Here is the web.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-application-context.xml </param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>errorPageUrl</param-name>
  <param-value>/pages/systemError.do</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
  <param-value>2</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
  <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY</param-name>
  <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
  <param-value>glass-x</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>search.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
</web-app>
```

It is the same file from the example. The only thing i changed is:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>search.xhtml</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list>
```

I changed from `*.jsf to *.xhtml`. I also changed the file ending in the `template > common.xhtml`:

```xml
<p:menuitem value="Search" url="/search.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-search" /> 
<p:menuitem value="New Product" url="/detail.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-document" />
```

to `*.xhtml`. I hope these changed can fix my problem. But that was not the answer.

Did anyone have a idea? I read some post from people who have a similar problem, but i don't resolve the problem.

i dind not have 10 reputation so i can't post a image of the project structure. Here is the link to the picture.
[Path of the project structure](http://s7.directupload.net/images/140130/6edhoqgc.jpg)

Comment: This bit seems wrong: `Information: Mojarra 2.2.0 ( ) für Kontext '' wird initialisiert.`. The context should be set to a not-empty string. WTP will use the project name by default. Are you overriding the context somewhere? Maybe on the `Modules` tab of the Tomcat config editor?

Comment: And the webapp folder does not have to be on the build path.

Comment: The WebApp Folder is also in the example in the webapp folder.

Comment: I have the `Information: Mojarra 2.2.0 ( ) für Kontext '' wird initialisiert.` in a diffrent project and this project works well.